# Error: cannot coerce type 'closure' to vector of type 'character'

Tags: r, shiny

can someone help me with this error?
I don't know whats wrong here.

I get the Error "Error: cannot coerce type 'closure' to vector of type 'character'" on my shiny Dashboard when inserting the password into the password field.

**UI**

```
    fluidRow(
    column(10),
    column(2,
           tagList(
             passwordInput("password", "Password:"),
             uiOutput("analyseTab")
           )
    )
  )
```

**Server**

```
output$analyseTab <- renderUI({

if(input$password == "shiny"){
  showTab("TabBox01","Tab_Analyse")
}
else{
  hideTab(inputId = "TabBox01", target = "Tab_Analyse")
}})
```

Thank you!

Comment: a fully working minimal code example would be helpful here, so that one can recreate your issue, like you have already been told in your other posts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting this error because of a bad use of output / renderUI.

I think an ObserveEvent is what your are looking for in this situation, instead of an UI output.

```
ui <- fluidPage(
  fluidRow(
    column(10),
    column(2,
           tagList(
             passwordInput("password", "Password:"),
             uiOutput("analyseTab")
           )
    )
  ),
  tabsetPanel(
    id = "TabBox01",
    tabPanel("tab1", 'A regular tab'),
    tabPanel("Tab_Analyse", "A password-hidden tab")
  )
  
  
)
server <- function(input, output, session) {
  observeEvent(input$password, {
    if(input$password == "shiny"){
      showTab("TabBox01","Tab_Analyse")
      updateTabsetPanel(session, "TabBox01", selected = "Tab_Analyse")
    }
    else{
      hideTab(inputId = "TabBox01", target = "Tab_Analyse")
    }})
}


shinyApp(ui, server)
```